# Allow OPTIONS HTTP method with Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am working with Amazon S3 on a HTML5 CORS file uploader. It's working well, but I have still a very strange thing which is happening.

Before the **PUT** request to send the file, the browser always sends an **OPTIONS** request, which fails with a **403 FORBIDDEN** error code.

But the file is correctly transferred to S3 so what's happening ?

I tried to solve my problem by enabling all the HTTP methods, but it hasn't worked.

Here are the headers I am using for the **PUT** request:

```
AWSAccessKeyId:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Expires:1347882643
Signature:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

And some code stuff :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// bind the event listener
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progress_listener, false);
// open the XMLHttpRequest 
xhr.open('PUT', signed_url, true);

// when the upload is completed call the callback function if supplied
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if(typeof callback == "function") {
        callback(this.status == 200, file.name, file_id);
        confirm_upload_success(file_id);
    }
};

// start sending
xhr.send(file);
```

Comment: Did you setup CORS correctly? http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Of course, but Amazon S3 doesn't allow you to put OPTIONS in the allowed HTTP methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** This bug has been fixed by Amazon :-)

**Carl@AWS / Sep 28, 2012 2:56 PM:**

> All,
>
> This bug should now be fixed and using pre-signed url's with CORS will
>   succeed.
>
> Thanks,

---

The problem you describe is an Amazon bug: It turns out that S3 is currently authenticating the OPTION call that is made in "preflight" for CORS and that fails (probably because the auth has been signed with for a PUT request not an OPTION request).

It's already on their radar as you can see here: [CORS works with public data, but fails to work with pre-signed request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=378235)

**Carl@AWS / Sep 5, 2012 1:00 PM:**

> Thank you, and everybody else, for the report. You are correct that
>   pre-signed requests returning an error on the initial OPTIONS request.
>   We are working on this issue and expect to add this support shortly. I
>   don't have a timeline for the availability of the change but I will
>   update this thread with more information when I have that. If you have
>   any follow up questions let me know.

So just ignore it and they'll fix it.

Comment: But don't forget to update CORS policy in S3 bucket. With default policy *PUT* request works with Postman, for example, but doesn't work from browser because of *OPTIONS* request